# Notificación cuando la base de datos se actualiza

Tags: vb.net

Buenas, estoy realizando un sistema en Visual Basic y a pesar que he leído e intentado muchas formas, no logro hacer que cuando se realice un pedido, en el sistema se reciba una notificación.
Explico cómo funciona: Tengo una aplicación en B4A (Android) donde los usuarios realizan sus pedidos, esto funciona correctamente, ahora estoy realizando la parte de "administrador" en Visual Basic, donde el administrados deberá recibir una notificación cuando a la tabla "pedidos" (de mi base de datos a la cual se le inserta un registro cuando un usuario hace un pedido) se le inserte un nuevo registro, pero no consigo esto, por ahora lo tengo con un Timer y haciendo que cada 5 segundos se actualice el DataGridView (es donde estoy mostrando los datos).
Creo que no es necesario añadir el código, pero si me lo solicitan lo paso.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instala este nuget en tu proyecto:

[image: Instlación de paquete nuget]
No se que estructura tenga tu tabla, pero necesitas crear una clase que la represente, algo así:

```
public class Pedidos
    public Property Id As Integer
    public Property Proveedor As String
    public Property Fecha As Datetime
    // mas campos que tenga tu tabla
End Class
```

Luego, tu clase formulario sería mas o menos así:

```
Imports TableDependency.SqlClient
Imports TableDependency
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports TableDependency.EventArgs
Imports TableDependency.Enums

Public Class Form1
    Dim mapper As ModelToTableMapper(Of Pedidos)
    Dim dep As SqlTableDependency(Of Pedidos)
    Dim conexion As SqlConnection

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ' aquí inicializamos la variable mapper
        mapper = New ModelToTableMapper(Of Pedidos)()

        ' y aqui asocias cada campo en tu tabla para cada propiedad en la clase que definimos antes
        ' cambia los valores a los que tu usas en tu tabla
        mapper.AddMapping(Function(a) (a.Id), "Id")
        mapper.AddMapping(Function(a) (a.Proveedor), "Proveedor")
        mapper.AddMapping(Function(a) (a.Fecha), "Fecha")
        ' etc
        ' connectionString es la cadena de conexión a tu base de datos
        ' en vez de TblPedidos pones el nombre de la tabla de la que quieres recibir las notificaciones
        dep = New SqlTableDependency(Of Pedidos)("connectionString", "TblPedidos", mapper)

        'luego definimos el método que maneja el evento de cambio en la tabla
        AddHandler dep.OnChanged, AddressOf OnChange

        ' y por ultimo le indicamos al objeto que empiece a recibir notificaciones de labase de datos
        dep.Start()

        ' antes de que tu programa se cierre no olvides llamar a dep.Stop()
    End Sub


    Private Sub OnChange(sender As Object, e As RecordChangedEventArgs(Of Pedidos))
        ' en esta variable guardas el registro que cambió
        Dim entidadConCambio = e.Entity

        If e.ChangeType = ChangeType.Delete Then
            ' aquí haces lo que quieras hacer cuando se haya eliminado un registro
            ' el regisdtro eliminado está en la variable entidadConCambio
        End If

        If e.ChangeType = ChangeType.Insert Then
            ' aqui haces lo que quieras hacer cuando se haya insertado un registro

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Básicamente es eso, obvio lo adaptas a tu código. **Nota**: Por lo que se, funciona con SQL Server 2008 como mínimo.

Answer (score 0):

La forma genérica de hacerlo (independiente de la base de datos que utilices) sería esa: tener un servicio o aplicación que cada cierto tiempo compruebe mediante una consulta si hay modificaciones.

Otra forma sería que el mismo proceso que realiza la grabación en la base de datos notificara de alguna forma a la aplicación de administración que se ha realizado un cambio. La forma de notificar dependerá de la arquitectura de la aplicación (por ejemplo de si ambos procesos se ejecutan en la misma máquina)

Otra solución más específica sería utilizar algún mecanismo de notificaciones que te pueda ofrecer el sistema de base de datos que estés utilizando. Por ejemplo en SQL Server tienes las "notificaciones de consulta", desde .NET puedes utilizar la clase [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) para gestionar este tipo de notificaciones.

Comment: Cada vez entiendo menos el criterio que sigue la gente para dar los votos negativos. ¿Es sólo por conseguir medallas?